# md5 matching password using mysqli_query?

Tags: php

i am currently having problem matching my md5 password in database with data entered by the user, i know that i should not use such type of password matching but i want to know why this does not work.

here is my login script

```
 <?php
//Login Script
if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
    $user_login = $_POST["user_login"]; 
    $password_login = $_POST["password_login"];
    $md5password_login = md5($password_login);
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users2 WHERE username='$user' AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1"); // query the person

    //Check for their existance
    $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned

    if ($userCount == 1) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
             $rahul = $row["id"];
        }

        $_SESSION["id"] = $rahul;
        $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
        $_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
       exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Whenever i enter the correct details, it throws your information is incorrect, earlier it used to work in mysql_query but now it's deprecated.

Comment: Please look into the [PHP documentation article here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) about why using `md5` for password is a **terrible** idea.

Comment: i know it's a terrible idea, please try to understand i already told you i am not going to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect pass in a user & pass in here :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users2 WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass' LIMIT 1");
```

you should change it :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users2 WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: it returns this : string(32) "d810ac398d1ae22533ab2b81ae45ccbb" string(32) "16284e99f5ff95c4e4dea8731ce48da2" Both are different, why?

Comment: hmm... it strange, did you use `md5('your password')` to pass in database ? did you use any hash ? are you use native php to `md5` your password ?
 can you provide your function to encrypt your password to the database ?

Comment: oh! i found it, in registering user i was encrypting email and storing it as password. thanks